# Coefficient of Determination in case of Multi-Response Model

Tags: multiple-regression, multivariate-analysis, linear-model, r-squared

In case of single response multiple linear model, I can write the population coefficient of determination as,

**Eq:1**
\begin{equation}
\rho^2 = \frac{\sigma_{Xy}^t\Sigma_{XX}^{-1}\sigma_{Xy}}{\sigma_{y}^2}
\label{eq:rsq}
\end{equation}

This gives the proportion of variance in the response explained by the model. What is the equivalent expression for a model with multiple response. For instance, consider a model with $m$ responses as,

**Eq:2**
\begin{equation}
E[\mathbf{Y}|X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_p] = \boldsymbol{\mu}_{Y} +\mathbf{B}\left(\mathbf{X} - \boldsymbol{\mu}_X\right)
\end{equation}

When I estimate this model with OLS, I will obtain estimated coefficient of determination $R^2$ for each response. What will the population expression for the coefficient of determination. I suppose I will obtain $m\times m$ matrix of $R^2$ as,

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\rho_1^2 & \rho_{12} & \ldots & \rho_{1m} \\
\rho_{21} & \rho_2^2 & \ldots & \rho_{2m} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
\rho_{m1} & \rho_{m2}^2 & \ldots & \rho_m^2 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

I can imagine the diagonal elements of this matrix as explained variation, but what can be the interpretation of the off diagonal elements?

In summary, following are to my main question:

- How can I calculate population coefficient of determination from the covariance structure in case of model with multiple response variables
- What will be the interpretation of off diagonal elements in the coefficient of determination matrix

**Update:**

- I can measure the numerator part of (**Eq:1**) as the covariance of fitted response.